# Fine Uploader returning empty response from server or incorrectly reporting an erro

Tags: json, fine-uploader

I have an implementation of fine-uploader running. I am experiencing the following issue across a variety of different browser/security combinations.

**Issue** (CORS request, between two non secure domains)
With debug mode on I am seeing (what looks like) a successful response in the log, however the front-end JS continues to throw an error. Please see log dump below.

```
[FineUploader 3.9.1] Received 1 files or inputs. jquery.fineuploader-3.9.1.js:164
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js:5374
[FineUploader 3.9.1] Sending upload request for 0 jquery.fineuploader-3.9.1.js:164
XHR finished loading: "http://mydomain/endpoint.php". jquery.fineuploader-3.9.1.js:5417
[FineUploader 3.9.1] xhr - server response received for 0 jquery.fineuploader-3.9.1.js:164
[FineUploader 3.9.1] responseText = Array
(
    [promo_id] => 136
    [qquuid] => 8dde1abb-e0b8-4bf2-abbe-14fb7b958c81
    [qqtotalfilesize] => 3638
)
{"success":true,"uploadName":"136\/87fd93e5e656db4c8e239b3f00575a1e.jpg"} jquery.fineuploader-3.9.1.js:164
[FineUploader 3.9.1] Received response status 200 with body: Array
(
    [promo_id] => 136
    [qquuid] => 8dde1abb-e0b8-4bf2-abbe-14fb7b958c81
    [qqtotalfilesize] => 3638
)
{"success":true,"uploadName":"136\/87fd93e5e656db4c8e239b3f00575a1e.jpg"} jquery.fineuploader-3.9.1.js:164
[FineUploader 3.9.1] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token A)
```

I can confirm the file is successfully uploading to my server, so the debug data is correct. Im a little confused as to why the plugin is not able to parse the response correctly though. I assume when debug is not on, only the JSON data is in the responseText, therefore the handler should be able to parse the {JSON response} correctly - can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong here ? This is a live client project and is happening across both http and https.

Thanks in advance
J

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not returning a valid JSON response.  This can be seen in the debug output from Fine Uploader.

Here is what your server is returning:

"Array
(
    [promo_id] => 136
    [qquuid] => 8dde1abb-e0b8-4bf2-abbe-14fb7b958c81
    [qqtotalfilesize] => 3638
)
{"success":true,"uploadName":"136/87fd93e5e656db4c8e239b3f00575a1e.jpg"}"

And here is what your server should be returning:
{"success":true,"uploadName":"136/87fd93e5e656db4c8e239b3f00575a1e.jpg"}"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I agree that is what is causing the issue. Im not sure why the array is being returned however. Here are the relevant parts of my endpoint.php

$result = $uploader->handleUpload($path);
echo json_encode($result);

Should I need to be doing any additional encoding?

Comment: The problem is likely in the return value of your handleUpload method.  You must return a valid JSON object, and that apparently is not happening.  You'll need to take a closer look at this method in your server code.

Comment: Yep, it would seem so, however nothing has changed in this part of the logic from the base. I'm confused as to where the additional array objects are (that aren't getting converted to the JSON object) on the backend? Any ideas? 

$target = $this->getUniqueTargetPath($uploadDirectory, $name);

            if ($target){
                $this->uploadName = basename($target);

                if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)){
                    return array('success'=> true, 'uploadName' => $pid.$this->uploadName);
                }
            }

Comment: Im really stumped on this one! handler.php is returning the two variables 'success' and 'uploadName'. There is no mention of the other variables that are contained within the mystery array?

Comment: I think I have resolved the array + json object response by disabling my handler for older IE browsers (not sure why this code block was executing!!)... So I can now upload, however I noticed that from https to https in a CORS request in Chrome I get no body response at all, the exact same code in firefox works perfectly. Any ideas on this? I usually find Chrome to be the more lenient browser, but not in this case.
Cheers
J